# How can we convert a list to a dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe

I have this list.

```
[{'place_id': 166143393,
  'licence': 'Data © OpenStreetMap contributors, ODbL 1.0. https://osm.org/copyright',
  'osm_type': 'way',
  'osm_id': 312345183,
  'boundingbox': ['42.2845543', '42.2846072', '-71.155034', '-71.154969'],
  'lat': '42.28458075',
  'lon': '-71.1550015',
  'display_name': '1, Corey Street, Highland, West Roxbury, Boston, Suffolk County, Massachusetts, 02132, United States',
  'class': 'amenity',
  'type': 'parking_space',
  'importance': 0.42099999999999993},
 {'place_id': 281831447,
  'licence': 'Data © OpenStreetMap contributors, ODbL 1.0. https://osm.org/copyright',
  'osm_type': 'way',
  'osm_id': 14458078,
  'boundingbox': ['34.429939194631',
   '34.430039194631',
   '-103.17697387248',
   '-103.17687387248'],
  'lat': '34.42998919463088',
  'lon': '-103.17692387248321',
  'display_name': '102, Wilmington, Clovis, Curry County, New Mexico, 88101, United States',
  'class': 'place',
  'type': 'house',
  'importance': 0.22100000000000003},
 'no data for: 209 Milwaukee - New Berlin',
 'no data for: 209 Milwaukee - New Berlin',
 'no data for: 85 Suffolk - Farmingdale 1',
 {'place_id': 90856391,
  'licence': 'Data © OpenStreetMap contributors, ODbL 1.0. https://osm.org/copyright',
  'osm_type': 'way',
  'osm_id': 16484524,
  'boundingbox': ['34.3417839', '34.3523', '-78.633921', '-78.6259801'],
  'lat': '34.348635',
  'lon': '-78.626565',
  'display_name': 'Lewis Burchett Road, Columbus County, North Carolina, 28442, United States',
  'class': 'highway',
  'type': 'residential',
  'importance': 0.4},
 {'place_id': 160710562,
  'licence': 'Data © OpenStreetMap contributors, ODbL 1.0. https://osm.org/copyright',
  'osm_type': 'way',
  'osm_id': 291006990,
  'boundingbox': ['-27.2851413', '-27.280567', '-60.4206607', '-60.4206312'],
  'lat': '-27.2827433',
  'lon': '-60.4206404',
  'display_name': 'San Diego, Villa Berthet, Municipio de Villa Berthet, Departamento San Lorenzo, Chaco, 3545, Argentina',
  'class': 'highway',
  'type': 'residential',
  'importance': 0.4},
 'no data for: 198 Greater Nebraska',
 'no data for: 173 Atlanta - Duluth3',
 {'place_id': 286386914,
  'licence': 'Data © OpenStreetMap contributors, ODbL 1.0. https://osm.org/copyright',
  'osm_type': 'way',
  'osm_id': 14973095,
  'boundingbox': ['35.180786214008',
   '35.180886214008',
   '-95.609207364528',
   '-95.609107364528'],
  'lat': '35.180836214008316',
  'lon': '-95.60915736452755',
  'display_name': '189, Fargo, Pittsburg County, Oklahoma, 74425, United States',
  'class': 'place',
  'type': 'house',
  'importance': 0.22100000000000003}]
```

I thought a simple one-liner would do it.

```
df = DataFrame(appendlist)
```

That gives me this error.

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'keys'
```

Any thoughts on how to handle this kind of thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are missing data in you dict. it needs to be the same format to convert dict to dataframe. you could either convert "no data for" line to the same format or just skip it.

```
pd.DataFrame([item for item in data if "no data for" not in item ])
```

update with missing data:

```
import pandas as pd
res = []
counter = 1
for item in data:
    if "no data for" in item:
        name = item.replace("no data for: ",  "")
        res.append({'place_id': counter,
              'licence': 'Data © OpenStreetMap contributors, ODbL 1.0. https://osm.org/copyright',
              'osm_type': '',
              'osm_id': "",
              'boundingbox': ['','','',''],
              'lat': '',
              'lon': '',
              'display_name': name,
              'class': '',
              'type': '',
              'importance': ""})
        counter += 1
    else:
        res.append(item)
        
pd.DataFrame(res)
```

Comment: I need to use this approach, because I have to join this dataframe to another, based on index, so skipping items won't work for me. I tried a couple ways to get this working, but it keeps dropping 5 records. How can this code be modified to convert everything to a dataframe, even the records with 'no data for:'?

Answer (score 2):

Your list has some rogue strings:

```
 'no data for: 198 Greater Nebraska',
 'no data for: 173 Atlanta - Duluth3'
```

Remove them before passing the list to the `DataFrame` constructor.

E.g. `pd.DataFrame([d for d in yourlist if isinstance(d, dict)])`

Comment: Thanks! How can I use this technique and keep all the records, including the 'no data for:' records. I want to keep those as placeholders.

Answer (score 1):

That's look like a JSON object not a list.
First open empty list for each ID

```
list = list.contect
list = json.loads(list)
place_id =    []
boundingbox = []
.....
for x in range (len(list))
    place_id.append(list[x]['place_id'])
    boundingbox .append(list[x]['boundingbox '])
    ....
df = pd.DataFrame({'place_id':place_id,'boundingbox':boundingbox},columns = 
['place_id','boundingbox'])
```